# Search string in private github repos of the organization

Tags: github-api

I have some code that nobody knows if it is in any of the company repos. I want to use the github api to automate the search, like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" "https://api.github.com/search/code?q=<SEACH_TEXT>"
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "total_count": 0,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [

  ]
}
```

Using the web UI results do return. When I try this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" "https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:<ORG_NAME>+<SEACH_TEXT>+in:file"
```

I'm getting

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.",
      "resource": "Search",
      "field": "q",
      "code": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/v3/search/"
}
```

Even though my token seem to have the permissions.